# Why can I access package-scoped class via companion object from a different package?

Tags: scala

Say I have the following code in a `Quark.scala` file:

```scala
package a

object Quark {
    def apply(): Quark = new Quark()
}

private[a] class Quark {
    def foo(): String = "bar"
}
```

And the following code in a `Main.scala` file:

```scala
package b

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val quark = Quark()
        println(quark.foo())
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't seem to mind that I'm accessing `foo()` from outside of package `a`. This seems strange to me. I would have assumed that the class type `Quark`, being denoted as `private[a]`, would not be accessible outside of package `a` even if accessed through its companion object. How should I understand this? Where is this documented?

After all, this is not valid:

```scala
package b

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val quark = new Quark() // This complains!
        println(quark.foo())
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK it is possible - `private[a]` prevents you from using the type explicitly (in signature, calling `new`) but here it's something like "`Quotes.apply()` returns some type which has method `foo()` and then calls `foo()` on it` - `Quotes.type` is public, `apply()` is public, `foo()` is public, it all is legal". You'd have to `private[a] def apply` as well. You can consider this a loophole but it is what it is. There are cases (in Scala but in Java as well AFAIR) where doing something with types explicitly is illegal, but if it's inferred or intermediate result, then the compiler allows it.

Comment: Not reproducible. For my compiler, it stops immediately with `Not found: Quark` at `val quark = Quark()`. You aren't importing anything from the `a`-package in your `Main`, it has no reasons to compile, and it doesn't.